# FormView IBindableTemplate can't get new values out of FormViewUpdateEventArgs e

Tags: asp.net

I have dynamic forms that are build from xml. I can generate the form but I can't get new values from it. I get only the old values that were generated. I would like to update values that are diffrent from old. I think the problem is that I override the new values on page_init with old ones?

This is a dropbox link to my UI for better understanding what I want to achive : https://www.dropbox.com/s/nacs9ohgjxefft9/FormView.png?dl=0#

```
public sealed class FormViewEditTemplate : IBindableTemplate
{
    public FormViewEditTemplate(ListItemType type, mmXMLdoc.mmXMLdoc editXmlForm)
    {
        templateType = type;
        _editXmlForm = editXmlForm;

    }
    //This method provides a way to insert an instance of text and controls into the specified container.
    void ITemplate.InstantiateIn(Control container)
    {
        tabela = new Table();
        tabs = new TabContainer();
        tapPanel = new TabPanel();
        row = new TableRow();
        switch (templateType)
        {

            case ListItemType.EditItem:

                List<XmlElement> Controls = _editXmlForm.getNodCollection("//Tabs");
                if (Controls.Count > 0)
                {
                    //pridobimo tabe za formo
                    foreach (XmlElement ctrlItem in Controls)
                    {
                        var ControlsItems = _editXmlForm.getNodCollection("./Controls", "Control", -1, ctrlItem);
                        tabela = new Table();
                        tapPanel = new TabPanel();
                        tapPanel.ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                        tapPanel.HeaderText = ctrlItem.GetAttribute("name").ToString();
                        //pridobimo podatke za formo
                        //var controls1 = ctrlItem.SelectNodes("//Controls");
                        foreach (XmlElement ctrl in ControlsItems)
                        {
                            string name = _editXmlForm.gStr("./@name", -1, ctrl) + Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                            string label = _editXmlForm.gStr("./@label", -1, ctrl);
                            string width = _editXmlForm.gStr("./@width", -1, ctrl);
                            string type = _editXmlForm.gStr("./@type", -1, ctrl);
                            string value = String.Empty;
                            string helpnote = _editXmlForm.gStr("./HelpNote", -1, ctrl);
                            string boundfield = _editXmlForm.gStr("./BoundField", -1, ctrl);
                            row = new TableRow();
                            TableCell cell = new TableCell();
                            switch (type)
                            {
                                case "TextBox":

                                    //The TemplateField allows for a mix of HTML markup, Web controls, and data-binding syntax.
                                    Label lbl_item = new Label();
                                    lbl_item.Font.Bold = true;
                                    lbl_item.Text = label + ": ";
                                    cell = new TableCell();
                                    cell.Controls.Add(lbl_item);
                                    row.Controls.Add(cell);


                                    TextBox txt_item = new TextBox();
                                    txt_item.ID = boundfield;
                                    txt_item.Text = boundfield;
                                    txt_item.DataBinding += new EventHandler(txt_DataBind);
                                    cell = new TableCell();
                                    cell.Controls.Add(txt_item);
                                    row.Controls.Add(cell);

                                    break;
                                case "CheckBox":
                                    lbl_item = new Label();
                                    lbl_item.Font.Bold = true;
                                    lbl_item.Text = label + "<br/>";
                                    //The BoundField displays the value of specified DataSource field as text.
                                    BoundField bfield = new BoundField();
                                    bfield.HeaderText = label;
                                    bfield.DataField = boundfield;
                                    break;

                                default:
                                    break;
                            }

                            tabela.Controls.Add(row);

                        }
                        tapPanel.Controls.Add(tabela);
                        tabs.Controls.Add(tapPanel);
                    }
                }
                break;
            case ListItemType.Footer:

                Button saveButton = new Button();
                saveButton.Command += new CommandEventHandler(SaveButton_Command);
                saveButton.CommandName = "Update";
                saveButton.Text = "Save";
                saveButton.ID = "EditButton";
                container.Controls.Add(saveButton);
                break;
        }

        container.Controls.Add(tabs);
    }

IOrderedDictionary IBindableTemplate.ExtractValues(Control container)
    {
        OrderedDictionary dict = new OrderedDictionary();
        List<XmlElement> Controls = _editXmlForm.getNodCollection("//Tabs");
        if (Controls.Count > 0)
        {
            //pridobimo tabe za formo
            foreach (XmlElement ctrlItem in Controls)
            {
                var ControlsItems = _editXmlForm.getNodCollection("./Controls", "Control", -1, ctrlItem);

                foreach (XmlElement ctrl in ControlsItems)
                {
                    string type = _editXmlForm.gStr("./@type", -1, ctrl);
                    string boundfield = _editXmlForm.gStr("./BoundField", -1, ctrl);

                    switch (type)
                    {
                        case "TextBox":
                            TextBox tb = (TextBox)FindControlRecursive(container, boundfield);
                            if (tb != null)
                                dict[boundfield] = tb.Text;
                            break;
                        case "Label":
                            Label lb = (Label)FindControlRecursive(container, boundfield);
                            if (lb != null)
                                dict[boundfield] = lb.Text;
                            break;
                        case "CheckBox":
                            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)FindControlRecursive(container, boundfield);
                            if (cb != null)
                                dict[boundfield] = cb.Checked;
                            break;
                        case "DropDown":
                            DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)FindControlRecursive(container, boundfield);
                            if (ddl != null)
                                dict[boundfield] = ddl.SelectedValue;
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        return dict;
    }

    private Control FindControlRecursive(Control ctlRoot, string sControlId)
    {
        // if this control is the one we are looking for, break from the recursion
        // and return the control.
        if (ctlRoot.ID == sControlId)
        {
            return ctlRoot;
        }
        // loop the child controls of this parent control and call recursively.
        foreach (Control ctl in ctlRoot.Controls)
        {
            Control ctlFound = FindControlRecursive(ctl, sControlId);
            // if we found the control, return it.
            if (ctlFound != null)
            {
                return ctlFound;
            }
        }
        // we never found the control so just return null.
        return null;
    }
```

I call this in Page_init

protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        FormViewEdit.HeaderTemplate = new FormViewEditTemplate(ListItemType.Header, editXmlForm);
        FormViewEdit.EditItemTemplate = new FormViewEditTemplate(ListItemType.EditItem, editXmlForm);
        FormViewEdit.FooterTemplate = new FormViewEditTemplate(ListItemType.Footer, editXmlForm);
        FormViewEdit.ItemUpdating += new FormViewUpdateEventHandler(FormView1_ItemUpdating);

        EditFormView.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM " + UniqueTable + " WHERE " + PrimaryKey + "=" + ident;
EditFormView.DataBind();
```

}

```
protected void FormView1_ItemUpdating(object sender, FormViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        //TODO get all new values and make query string.            
        EditFormView.UpdateCommand = "UPDATE " + UniqueTable + " SET bla_Opis='" + e.NewValues["bla_Opis"] + "'  WHERE " + PrimaryKey + "=" + ident;
        EditFormView.Update();
        EditFormView.DataBind();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I used randomly generated id  for tap panel therfore I believe the the two way binding didnt work on post back. On every postback I got new id and the old data didnt find  control to bind the new values.

tapPanel.ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();